# using a function to output struct values

Tags: c++, function, data-structures

Hi I have just begun experimenting with structures. I'm try to run a very basic programme in which two points in a struct (x,y) are outputted by a function. I know it's very basic but Ive been trying all day and just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using namespace std;

void printPoint(const pointType& point); 

struct pointType 
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct pointType pos1;
    pos1.x = 10;
    pos1.y = 15;

    printPoint();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void printPoint(const pointType& point)
{

    //      
}
```

Comment: How would you output, say, a single `int` from a function? Take that, and modify it so it works with your `struct`.

Comment: Did you mean `printf("%d", point->x)` inside your function?

Comment: The idiomatic C++ answer would be to build an `operator<<` for iostreams, and use it with `std::cout`, a simpler way is to access the members directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you should define the structure before the function declaration or the function declaration should use an elaborated name that is the name of the structure with keyword struct

```
struct pointType {
int x;
int y;
};

void printPoint(const pointType& point);
```

or

```
void printPoint(const struct pointType& point); 

struct pointType {
int x;
int y;
};
```

Otherwise the compiler will not know what name pointType means in the function declaration.

The structure definition shall be ended with a semicolon

```
struct pointType {
int x;
int y;
};
```

In this statement

```
struct pointType pos1;
```

there is no need to specify keyword struct, You could write simpler

```
pointType pos1;
```

Also you could initialize the object the following way

```
struct pointType pos1 =  { 10, 15 };
```

The function call shall have an argument because it was declared as having a parameter. So instead of

```
printPoint();
```

write

```
printPoint( pos1 );
```

The function itself could look the following way

```
void printPoint(const pointType& point)
{
   std::cout << "x = " << point.x << ", y = " << point,y << std::endl;
}
```

Do not forget to include header `<iostream>`

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct pointType
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void printPoint(const pointType& point); 


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct pointType pos1;
    pos1.x = 10;
    pos1.y = 15;

    printPoint(pos1);


    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void printPoint(const pointType& point)
{
    cout << point.x << '\t' << point.y << endl;
    //      
}
```

Comment: Why suggest `printf` for a C++ question?

Comment: @JoeDF I have nothing against C. But if the OP is using C++ and trying to *learn* C++, idiomatic C++ answers are best.

Answer (score 1):

One of many possibilities is

```
void printPoint(const pointType& point){
  std::cout << "x:" << point.x << ", y:" << point.y << std::endl;
}
```

---

### Overload operator<<

However in case of more complicated logic of the output operation you can define `operator<<( std::ostream& oot, pointType const& p)` in your class. This is useful when you want do something additional when writing to output stream is made, or when what will be printed is not simply built-in type, so you cannot write `std::cout << point.x` directly. Maybe you want also to use different ***locale*** or ***facet*** for printing variables of particular type so you would also ***imbue*** a stream inside overloaded operator.

```
struct pointType {
  int x;
  int y;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &out, pointType const& p);
    ^
  // needed when access to private representation is required,
  // here it is not the case, friend specifier not required
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &out, pointType const& p) {
  //.. do something maybe
  out << "x:" << point.x << ", y:" << point.y << std::endl;
  //.. maybe something more
  return out;
}
```

So now you can use it simply in the usual way output stream is used:

```
int main() {
  pointType p;
  std::cout << p;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why friend though? The data members are public.